# ValueError: The array returned by a function changed size between calls when using scipy.fsolve()

Tags: python, scipy, solver

I am trying to use scipy.optimize.fsolve() to check if some lines intersect some planes but keep getting the error above. My code is:

```
def colision_detection(self, moving_mic, final_position):
    other_mics = [mic for mic in self.mics if mic != moving_mic]

    segments = [(motor.position, mic.position - motor.position) for mic in other_mics for motor in mic.motors]
    planes = [(motor.position, np.cross(moving_mic.position - motor.position, final_position - motor.position)) for motor in moving_mic.motors]

    def intersection(t, plane, segment):
        # n*(r-b)=0

        r = t * segment[1] + segment[0]
        n = plane[1]
        b = plane[0]

        return n*(r-b)

    for plane in planes:
        for segment in segments:
            try:
                ans = fsolve(intersection, x0=0, args=(plane, segment))
                self.logger.info(ans)

                if  0<= ans <=1:
                    return False

            except Exception as error:
                self.logger.exception(error)
    
    return True
```

I keep getting the error:

```
ValueError: The array returned by a function changed size between calls
```

The position of the mics and the motors are three dimensional numpy arrays.

Comment: Please post a [example].

Comment: how are you calling `scipy.optimize.fsolve()`? you havent included the code that your question is about...